# Vite with aws-sdk build failed - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, vite

I got error below than I inspect the error found - AWS$6.STS.prototype
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

It build successfully. And I can upload file to aws s3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, except the page doesn't load. This is on the Vite production build when I `npm run build`, doesn't happen on the dev server, so it must be related to the Rollup build.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue during build - any updates?

Comment: A quick solution is by replacing `aws-sdk` dependency with individual dependencies like `@aws-sdk/client-s3`.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the rollup version needs to be updated to v22 within vite.

For now there's a workaround:

```js
export const updateCommonjsPlugin = (): Plugin => {
  const commonJs22 = commonjs({
    include: [/node_modules/],
    extensions: [".js", ".cjs"],
    strictRequires: true,
  });

  return {
    name: "new-common-js",
    options(rawOptions) {
      const plugins = Array.isArray(rawOptions.plugins)
        ? [...rawOptions.plugins]
        : rawOptions.plugins
        ? [rawOptions.plugins]
        : [];

      const index = plugins.findIndex(
        (plugin) => plugin && plugin.name === "commonjs"
      );
      if (index !== -1) {
        plugins.splice(index, 1, commonJs22);
      }

      const nextConfig = { ...rawOptions, plugins };
      return commonJs22.options.call(this, nextConfig);
    },
  };
};
```

And in `vite.config.ts` add it to the plugins

```js
plugins: [updateCommonjsPlugin()],
```

More about this on [this GH thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1769#issuecomment-1172512907)